# Why is this loop returning duplicate results?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating some code to loop through the files in a folder and delete the ones that aren't in a query based on the invoice number in the filename. It's based on the code I found [here](http://codevba.com/office/loop_files_in_folder.htm#.XYJFJeRYaUk). The problem is that when I use Debug.Print to see the results it's returning several duplicates and doesn't return all of the files that are not in the query.

```
Sub DeleteInvoices()

Dim strFile As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim TestStr As String

    strPath = "E:\groups\folder\folder2\"
    strFile = Dir("E:\groups\folder\folder2\*")
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    If IsNull(DLookup("[qry_InvPDFList]![Invoice#]", "qry_InvPDFList", "[qry_InvPDFList]![Invoice#] = " & QUOTE & Mid(strFile, 12, 6) & QUOTE)) Then
            TestStr = strPath & strFile
            End If
            Debug.Print TestStr
            strFile = Dir

         Loop
 EndSub
```

I am expecting it to return 50+ unique filenames without duplicates.

Why is this code returning duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Debug.Print` expression is **outside** of the `If` statement, therefore, it will print a value for *every* iteration of the `Do` loop, always printing the last value held by `TestStr`.

I would suggest changing the content of the loop to:

```
Do Until strFile = ""
    If IsNull(DLookup("[Invoice#]", "qry_InvPDFList", "[Invoice#] = '" & Mid(strFile, 12, 6) & "'")) Then
        TestStr = strPath & strFile
        Debug.Print TestStr
    End If
    strFile = Dir
Loop
```

---

You also have `EndSub` instead of `End Sub`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my issue. It's returning the results I expected now and confirms the code is working.